# Why does "ps aux | grep x" give better results than "pgrep x"?

Tags: command-line, bash, text

I've just tried the following command on my Ubuntu, it doesn't show a thing:

```
pgrep php5
```

shouldn't it return the process ID of php5 (which the following command just does)?:

```
ps aux | grep php5
```

So, what's the difference between these two commands?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

#### `ps aux` includes the full command line (path and parameters), while pgrep only looks at the *first 15 characters of* the executable's names

`ps aux` returns the full command line of each process, while `pgrep` only looks at the names of the executables.

That means that *grepping* `ps aux` output will match anything that occurs in the path or the parameters of a process' binary: e.g. `

- `ps aux | grep php5` will match `/usr/share/php5/i-am-a-perl-script.pl`
- but `pgrep php5` won't

Take an example from my system -- only we'll use python instead of `php5`:

- **`ps aux | grep python`** gives us:

```
izx       2348  0.0  0.7 514928 15644 ?        Sl   Jun24   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/unity-lens-video/unity-lens-video
izx       2444  0.0  0.9 547392 18864 ?        Sl   Jun24   0:01 /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/unity-scope-video-remote/unity-scope-video-remote
root      2805  0.0  0.5  95436 12204 ?        S    Jun24   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/system-service/system-service-d
izx       6272  0.0  2.9 664400 60320 ?        SNl  Jun24   1:16 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/update-manager --no-focus-on-map
root     11729  0.0  0.9 180508 19516 ?        S    Jun25   0:00 python /usr/lib/software-properties/software-properties-dbus
```

- But **`pgrep python`** returns only `11729`, which you'll see from the above list is:

```
root     11729  0.0  0.9 180508 19516 ?        S    Jun25   0:00 python /usr/lib/software-properties/software-properties-dbus
```

Comment: "pgrep -l" also truncates the process to 15 characters, which is probably a bug but has been like this for ages

Comment: Well it's in launchpad as an upstream bug as of 2008 :) "top and ps truncate command after 15 chars" https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/procps/+bug/295876

Comment: Hah, this explains it, from comment #3: *This is due to the fact that some procedures of procs get the command name from `/proc/<pid>/stat` but not from `/proc/<pid>/cmdline`*. OK, @Thorsen, you win the bug spray, it's a bug :P

Comment: Thank you so much. According to your answer, pgrep is quite an unreasonable command, because it could well ignore all the running process in some circumstances(e.g.,my php5). Is there any other convincible reason that this command should exist?

Comment: pgrep and the related pkill are useful but just need to be treated with a little care. Here's a quick hack that does something like pgrep: `ps alx|awk '{print $3"\t"$13}'|sed 's/\(.*\t\).*\/\(.*\)/\1 \2/'` 
It prints the PID next to the full process name, but it may have other problems of course :)

Comment: @xczzhh `pgrep` is not an unreasonable command. It works well and as designed. The issue is simply you were missing an option when you run it, you can't blame `pgrep` for that. Using `ps aux | grep xxx` is unreliable so need hacks to filter out `grep` itself from the output and might give false positives like with `ps aux | grep root`.

Comment: This should be in an anti-drug commercial, the creators of bash tools were so blazed on LSD they thought things like this were well designed

Answer (score 97):

The `ps aux | grep x` command gives "better" results than `pgrep x` essentially because you are missing an option with the latter.

Simply use the `-f` option for `pgrep` to search the full command line and not only the process name which is its default behavior, eg:

```
pgrep -f php5
```

Unlike the `ps | grep` construction with which you need to filter out the `grep` line or use pattern tricks, `pgrep` just won't pick itself by design.

Moreover, should your pattern appear in `ps` `USER` column, you'll get unwanted processes in the output, `pgrep` doesn't suffer from this flaw.

If you want full details instead of just the pids, you can use:

```
ps wup $(pgrep -f python)
```

which is simpler and more reliable than

```
ps aux | grep python | grep -v grep
```

or

```
ps aux | grep p[y]thon
```

Comment: Also add the `-a` (`--list-full`) option if you want to see the full command line and not just the pid.  (Older pgrep had no `-a`, [did this on `-fl`](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=526355#15).)

Comment: The original question was asking about the difference but this actually gives those of us trying to get `pgrep` to play nice the solution. +1

Comment: @2rs2ts Thanks, I was indeed missing to answer to the question asked. Fixed now.

Comment: In some cases when programs modify `/proc/self/cmdline` to be "descriptive", `pgrep -fa ruby` will not match eg. `puma 3.3.0 (tcp://localhost:3000) [MIQ: Web Server Worker]`, while the "dumber" `pgrep -a ruby` will.  Not sure if the latter may be fooled too.

Comment: @BeniCherniavsky-Paskin I guess that could have been a comment to the question, since it apply to both `pgrep` and `ps`.

Comment: `ps wup` is a nice suggestion. I'd recommend adding another 'w' making it `ps wwup ...` to ensure that the output doesn't get truncated to the width of the terminal

Answer (score 1):

```
diff <(ps aux|grep x) <(pgrep x) # :)
```

Comment: This may answer the answer the question - but perhaps you can expand your answer to explain what this one line command does.

Answer (score 1):

At this time, `ps` will give more complete output than `pgep -f` as pgrep is limited to the first 4,096 characters (often affecting Java users looking for the entry class of a Java program with a long classpath). The bug tracking this is: https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/issues/86

Comment: Looked forever for this.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be better... when I tried to look for the tmux server process,

```
pgrep -l tmux
```

showed it, but

```
ps aux | grep tmux
```

won't show it as the server but shows it as the command that triggered the start of the server. (`tmux new -s foo`)