# ps aux | grep with a dot

Tags: command-line, grep, ps

I'm trying to write a script which greps for a running process.

I'm trying to avoid the actual grep from coming back from the `ps aux` output.

However I'm getting varying results if I use a dot or not:

`ps aux | grep [s]elenium` doesn't return anything.

`ps aux | grep [s]elenium.jar` returns the grep command:

```
beebee   36155  0.0  0.0  15940   956 pts/0    S+   16:20   0:00 grep --color=auto selenium.jar
```

Why is that?

Comment: You're matching exact string with s character followed elenium. Actual string contains more than that. Since it's jar file it begins with `java` command. My approach would be just to match `selenium` string and pipe into `grep -v grep` to remove grep command itself

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess you have a file named `selenium.jar` but no file called `selenium` in your current folder.

If you run

```
 ps aux | grep [s]elenium.jar
```

the shell will try to replace `[s]elenium.jar` with matching files names from the current folder. If there is a file called `selenium.jar` that will match and `[s]elenium.jar` will be replaced by `selenium.jar`.

The shell will then execute the command with the replaced value, i.e.

```
ps aux | grep selenium.jar
```

To avoid this quote the regex to protect it from the shell:

```
ps aux | grep '[s]elenium.jar'
```

Comment: I see, I've just tested this and it's exactly as you described. I didn't know that the shell will mess with a piped grep! Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a reference for that? I didn't know that filenames in the current folder could be substituted in a grep regex, and I can't find it in `man grep`, for instance.

Comment: @Jos: This isn't a function of  `grep` but of the shell: When you run a command in the shell the shell first splits it into "words" and then tries to expand each "word" according to some rules. See the ["EXPANSION" section of the bash manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/bash.1.html#contenttoc13)

Answer (score 5):

The problem here, as @Florian perceptively [figured out](https://askubuntu.com/a/787392/85695), is that the shell is expanding the glob characters in your search string to a matching filename before passing the string on to `grep`.

Running `ps aux | grep foo` is problematic since the `grep foo` command itself will match `foo` and so appear in the output. There are two common, if convoluted, workarounds for this. You either add a `grep -v grep` at the end of the pipe, or you use `grep [f]oo` instead. Since `grep` works with regular expressions, it will treat `[f]` as "any character in the list of characters inside the brackets". Since the only character in the brackets is `f`, `[f]oo` is equivalent to `foo`. However, the `grep` process showing up in the `ps` results will have the *string* `[f]oo` and is, therefore, not found by `grep`.

This becomes more complicated if, as seems to be the case for you, you have a file called `foo` in your current directory. Because you haven't quoted the expression you gave to `grep` (because you used `[s]elenium` and not `'[s]elenium'` or `"[s]elenium"`), the shell will treat it as a [glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29) and expand it to the matching file name. This renders the `[s]elenium` trick useless since what is actually passed to `grep` is `selenium` and not `[s]elenium` so the grep will match itself.

All this, however, only happens because you're not using the right tool for the job. As is so often the case, there's an app for that! 
Don't use `grep` + `ps`. Instead, use `pgrep` which is designed to do precisely what you want:

```
NAME
       pgrep,  pkill  -  look  up  or signal processes based on name and other
       attributes

SYNOPSIS
       pgrep [options] pattern
       pkill [options] pattern

DESCRIPTION
       pgrep looks through the  currently  running  processes  and  lists  the
       process IDs which match the selection criteria to stdout.  All the cri‐
       teria have to match.  For example,

         $ pgrep -u root sshd
```

So, in your case, you can just do

```
pgrep selenium
```

Or, since you're running it via `java`, use `-f` which searches through the entire command line:

```
pgrep -f selenium
```

Comment: I've tried `pgrep`, but i'm running selenium through `java -jar` so it's not finding it. See here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/157075/why-does-ps-aux-grep-x-give-better-results-than-pgrep-x

Comment: `pgrep` has `-f` flag which lets you use full command line to be searched. Try `pgrep -f selenium`

Comment: @Beebee what Serg said. You need `-f` to search through the entire comman line and not only the executable launched (java).

Comment: Since his problem was shell expansion of what it thought was the filename he provided on the command line, so he would have run into problems with pgrep as well.

Comment: @johnny No he wouldn't. The shell only meddles with the string because it contains meta characters (the square brackets). You would not need them with `pgrep`.

Comment: @johnny what Dubuque said. The only reason the shell was expanding the search string is because it had glob characters so the shell treated is as a glob. The only reason it had glob characters was because they are a classic trick to stop grep from appearing in the the output when parsing ps. And the only reason that grep was needed was because ps was being parsed. All of these problems disappear if you use pgrep which is designed for precisely this function.

Comment: @terdon This "the only reason" chain is crucial to the value of your answer and to even understanding why the heck the OP as using the brackets to begin with.   It would help if you moved this explanation into your answer, perhaps at the very beginning; it would really help clarify and motivate your answer.  At first I thought your answer was an irrelevant tangent, but this explanation finally makes it clear.

Comment: @DonHatch as @terdon said "The only reason it had glob characters was because they are a classic trick to stop grep from appearing in the the output when parsing ps.". I'm trying to write a script to start selenium standalone server if it's not already started. I was using a bash script to `ps aux | grep` for selenium and start it if there's no output.

Comment: @DonHatch is that better?

Answer (score 2):

You could exclude the "grep" after the *initial* grep:

```
ps aux | grep '[s]elenium.jar' | grep -v grep
```

Comment: That's a neat workaround cheers :)  But unfortunately doesn't actually answer the question of "why" :)

Comment: @drew, there's no need for `grep -v` if you're already using `grep '[s]elenium'`