# unresponsive gedit

Tags: command-line, gedit

I was running `gedit` from the command window for editing an xml file.
After editing the file,  I closed the `gedit` text editor window.

But the `gedit` process was till running in the command window.
So I forced stopped it using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>.

After that I want to use `gedit` to open another file.
How-long-so-ever I try, `gedit xxxx.xml`, `gedit` is not responding.

Can someone help me why it is not responding? And how to go forward?

Comment: `<Ctrl+Z>` is *suspend* for process, then you need to send it to background with `bg`. If you need to *stop* process, use `<Ctrl+C>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Find PID of gedit**

There is 2 way to find the PID of `gedit` :

- Open a terminal, type for example `ps -x` (you can also use `top`, `htop`, ...)

  [image]

  Here, we can that my `gedit` PID is 16694 (it's on the 1rst column on the left)
- using `pgrep`, you don't have to concate 2 command (`ps` + `grep`) :

  ```
   pgrep gedit
  ```

  This command return you the PID of `gedit`

---

**Force gedit to close**

use the command `kill -9 PID` where PID is the number you find with `ps -x`. In my example, `gedit` PID was 16694, so I must type `kill -9 16694`

You can now restart `gedit`, the non-responding state is totally wiped out.

NB: `kill` command works even on program open with `&` or `nohup` option.

NB-2 : If you have some applications running, it could be hard to find the PID, so just add a `grep` command to find it like that :

```
ps -x | grep gedit
```

Comment: look at `pgrep` as well instead of `ps -x | grep …`.

Comment: More on pgrep [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157075/why-does-ps-aux-grep-x-give-better-results-than-pgrep-x).

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> means suspending the process, so it continues to live but appears frozen. It is not terminated as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> would do.

There are basically four options what to do with a process suspended in a terminal:

- `fg %<job>` to continue it running in the foreground
- `bg %<job>` to continue it running in the background (so you can issue further commands)
- `kill %<job>` to terminate the process gracefully
- `kill -9 %<job>` to terminate the process forcefully (can cause unsaved changes etc.)

`<job>` is to be replaced with the job number given by the shell in square brackets (it’s `1` in the following example):

```sh
$ sleep 30
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 sleep 30
$ kill %1
$ # (enter any command or just press Enter to refresh the shell)
[1]+  Terminated              sleep 30
$
```

Comment: Nice little summary.