# Process id is constantly changing, and it can't be killed with name

Tags: process, grep, kill

I'm working with Ubuntu 16 through SSH, and facing an issue with it. I want to kill the process but can't find a way because it keeps changing the PID every time.

I'm using this command to check the process is running or not, here 'geth' is my process name

```
ps ax | grep geth
```

It showing me result as follows,

[image]

When I try kill the process with process name, it shows that

```
killall geth
```

> geth: no process found

Comment: Those aren't geth processes. Instead they are `grep` processes which on-completion automatically dies. Instead of using `ps ax | grep process_name` use `pgrep process_name`

Comment: Alright, so there isn't any process of geth running on the machine.

Comment: *Instead they are grep processes which on-completion automatically dies* How can I quit those from on-completion? P.S. I'm new to Ubuntu

Comment: There is no process called `geth` running on your machine. What you see is the process of you looking for such a process. Try replacing `geth` by `randomstring00300s0`.

Comment: @Div I have converted my comment into an answer.

Comment: Thanks! @Jos I understood now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ubuntu, [`grep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/grep.1posix.html) is an alias of `grep --color=auto`. You can confirm it by running `type grep`. When you run `grep something`, you're **actually** running `grep --color=auto something`.

Now when `grep` or any other command is ran, a process is created. As a result, even if some process doesn't even exist in the memory it'll produce an output which is obviously the `grep` process. For example, I have no application/program registered as `foo`. But even if I run `ps aux | grep foo`, I'll get:

```bsh
kulfy    13544  0.0  0.0  21532  1076 pts/0    S+   23:59   0:00 grep --color=auto foo
```

This process will automatically die once `grep` has processed all the output piped from `ps aux`.

You can use [`pgrep`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep) instead. It will show process id(s) of the running processes with the name passed as an argument. It doesn't need to be piped.

---

#### Further Reading:

- [How do I kill processes in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/104903/816190)
- [Why does "ps aux | grep x" give better results than "pgrep x"?](https://askubuntu.com/q/157075/816190)
- [How do I search for a process by name without using grep?](https://askubuntu.com/q/612315/816190)

Answer (score 1):

As already answered, you are looking at your own `grep` processes. Thats why there's a new PID for each process. If you want to exclude these lines containing `grep`, you can execute `ps ax | grep [g]eth`.